# Backwards Compatibility for Variable-length Messages

Tags: rosserial, rosmsg

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Say I have the following message definition, with messages passed from a microcontroller to a single-board computer over `rosserial`:

```
#RangeArray.msg
uint8 NUMBER_OF_SENSORS = 5
uint16[5] ranges
uint8[5] statuses
```

If I add/remove sensors and change the array size, I expect to lose any sort of backwards compatibility (any rosbags I've saved with these messages won't play nicely if I've changed to, say, `uint16[3] ranges`).

I'm wondering if I change the message definition [such that my arrays are of variable length](http://wiki.ros.org/msg#line-77), will this be backwards compatible even if `NUMBER_OF_SENSORS` differs between the two message definitions?

```
#RangeArray_old.msg
uint8 NUMBER_OF_SENSORS = 5
uint16[] ranges
uint8[] statuses

#RangeArray_new.msg
uint8 NUMBER_OF_SENSORS = 7
uint16[] ranges
uint8[] statuses
```

I'd expect to use `NUMBER_OF_SENSORS` to create a fixed-length array on the microcontroller side of `rosserial`, then use the variable-length vectors on the single-board computer side. I don't know if there's anything I'm not taking into account. Is this a common pattern to ensure compatibility?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/255718/backwards-compatibility-for-variable-length-messages/) by [nckswt](https://answers.ros.org/users/3362/nckswt/) on ROS Answers with karma: 539 on 2017-02-27

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you just want compatibility with old logs, maybe you can use [bag migration rules](http://wiki.ros.org/rosbag/migration).

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2017-02-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [nckswt](https://answers.ros.org/users/3362/nckswt/) on 2017-02-27**:
That'll make things a lot easier. Thanks!